# How does web.whatsapp.com work?

Tags: sockets, networking, web-applications, websocket

On most of the websites, I can see the web requests (GET, POST etc.) using Chrome's Network Tab in the Developer Tools. But on web.whatsapp.com, no requests are being made.

My understanding is that it sends and receives data using the phone, and the web version just displays the contents. But still, it has to communicate to the phone in order to be able to send or receive data.

How does this communication work? I'm a bit puzzled. I even tried using WireShark to inspect the network traffic, but no luck so far. Can anyone offer any insights?

Answer (score 1):

I think they use websockets. If the connection is already established when you open the network inspector in Chrome you won't see it, you will need to refresh. Look in the WS tab in the network inspector.